# Simple method for taking in an int, checking if it falls in a min/max, and returning that value.. not able to break out of method

Tags: java, input, methods, integer, output

I'm fairly new to java and I'm trying to make a simple method in a class that returns a user integer as long as it falls within certain boundaries. It seems to check the input correctly, but after that, it doesn't exit the method. Here is the method:

```
public int readInt(String prompt, int min, int max) {
    int userInt;
    boolean works = true;
    System.out.println(prompt);
    userInt = inputReader.nextInt();
    inputReader.nextLine();
    
    while(works = true) {
        if (userInt >= min && userInt <= max) {
            works = false;
        } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter value between " + min + " and " + max);
        userInt = inputReader.nextInt();
        inputReader.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return userInt;
}
```

And here is the main method. Running the method and just trying to print the int back out after. Never gets to the sout line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    UserIO userIO = new UserIOImpl();
    
    int userInt;
    
    userInt = userIO.readInt("Please enter a number between 1 and 10", 1, 10);
    System.out.println(userInt);
}
```

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm currently using NetBeans 12.0

Comment: You are assigning `true` to `works` in your while condition, not comparing them.

Comment: In other words, you should have written `while (works == true)`, not `while (works = true)`.  But you don't actually have to write `while (works == true)`, you can just write `while (works)`

Comment: Oh wow.. totally understand. thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "while(works = true)" make "while(works)"